# Why does SQL MERGE statement produce either truncation error or overflow error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine the following tblVendor table:

```
SourceSystemID (FK, tinyint, not null)
VendorIDInt (int, null)
VendorID (varchar(255), not null)
VendorName (varchar(50), null)
```

Here's a block that attempts to merge a SOURCE TABLE with my tblVendor table (utilizing the tblSourceSystem table):

```
MERGE tblVendor as TARGET
USING SYN_VENDOR_A as SOURCE
    ON TARGET.SourceSystemID = CAST(ISNULL((select SourceID from tblSourceSystem where SourceCode like SOURCE_SYSTEM), 0) as tinyint)
        AND TARGET.VendorID = SOURCE.VENDOR_KEY

WHEN MATCHED AND (SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'REG') THEN
    UPDATE
    SET
        SourceSystemID  = CAST(ISNULL((select SourceID from tblSourceSystem where SourceCode like SOURCE_SYSTEM), 0) as tinyint),
        VendorIDInt     = CAST(VENDOR_KEY as int),
        VendorID        = VENDOR_KEY,
        VendorName      = VENDOR_NAME

WHEN NOT MATCHED AND (SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'REG') THEN
    INSERT (
        SourceSystemID,
        VendorIDInt,
        VendorID,
        VendorName
    )
    VALUES (
        (SELECT CAST(ISNULL(SourceID, 0) as tinyint) from tblSourceSystem where SourceCode like SOURCE_SYSTEM), --varchar
        CAST(VENDOR_KEY as int), --varchar attemping to convert to an int
        VENDOR_KEY, --varchar
        VENDOR_NAME --varchar
    );
```

The tblVendor table was originally designed to where the SOURCE's VENDOR_KEY, a varchar, is always cast to an int prior to the data coming across. This isn't sustainable now because VENDOR_KEY's varchar overflowed the VendorIDInt column

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 524
>   
> The conversion of the varchar value '89617719042' overflowed an int column.

First try, I attempted to change the VendorIDInt column type to bigint and then cast VENDOR_KEY as bigint. This didn't work as an error showed

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 524
>   
> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Second try, I altered the tblVendor to add the VendorID varchar type column while commenting out the lines in the above merge statement involving casting and VendorIDInt. My thinking was, why even use the VendorIDInt column when I could just bring data across to the new varchar VendorID column? This also didn't work

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 524
>   
> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

I received the same error.

Third try, I ran out of ideas and simply ran the above merge statement as is with nothing commented out attempting to extract the data with both VendorIDInt and VendorID columns left in there. Yet again, same truncation error. No surprise there.

Why is this same truncation error appearing over and over?

The ultimate goal is to get data from the source table to my table and either the int column overflow error shows up or the truncation error shows up. I'm stuck in what seems like an impossible situation.

What other paths forward are there? Thanks.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the SYN_VENDOR_A table?

Comment: You showed the schema for `tblVendor` but not for `SYN_VENDOR`

Comment: I'm unaware of any triggers on that synonym table.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 try and add another filter to the merge condition, something like AND TRY_CONVERT(INT, SOURCE.VENDOR_KEY) IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the truncation error appeared is because of the synonym table's VENDOR_NAME column containing records with more than 50 characters.

The error was gone after using the following:

```
LEFT(VENDOR_NAME, 50)
```

The approach I used to solve the issue was by commenting out and isolating each column one by one and running the MERGE repeatedly.

It's a brute force method, I know. Feel free to post a more efficient strategy when faced with such an issue if anybody has one.